May a vendor add functions in a standard library header file without #including other headers?
Microsoft has std::max() in <utility>, so this compiles (Godbolt):
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    return std::max(2,3);
}

GCC doesn't have std::max() in <utility>, so it doesn't compile (Godbolt). And neither does clang (Godbolt).
CppReference doesn't list it as part of <utility>. It should be in <algorithm> (CppReference).
The MSVC header <utility> does not #include <algorithm> as allowed per [res.on.headers] (see this answer).  Instead, it implements 2 functions directly and forward-declares others:
_EXPORT_STD template <class _Ty, class _Pr>
_NODISCARD constexpr const _Ty&(max) (const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right, _Pr _Pred) noexcept(
    noexcept(_Pred(_Left, _Right))) /* strengthened */ {
    // return larger of _Left and _Right
    return _Pred(_Left, _Right) ? _Right : _Left;
}

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 28285) // (syntax error in SAL annotation, occurs when _Ty is not an integral type)
_EXPORT_STD template <class _Ty>
_NODISCARD _Post_equal_to_(_Left < _Right ? _Right : _Left) constexpr const _Ty& //
    (max) (const _Ty& _Left, const _Ty& _Right) noexcept(noexcept(_Left < _Right)) /* strengthened */ {
    // return larger of _Left and _Right
    return _Left < _Right ? _Right : _Left;
}
#pragma warning(pop)

_EXPORT_STD template <class _Ty, class _Pr>
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ty(max)(initializer_list<_Ty>, _Pr); // implemented in <algorithm>

_EXPORT_STD template <class _Ty>
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ty(max)(initializer_list<_Ty>); // implemented in <algorithm>

Is it allowed for a library vendor (like Microsoft) to add functions to arbitrary headers?
The problem I see is portability of my code. This way, my code only works with MSVC and not with others. Worse, I ended up in this situation because I used the feature "Optimize include graph" of Visual Studio, which then decided that <utility> requires less lines of code to be included (or whatever their metric is to optimize includes).
In the Standard, I only find (search term const T& max) the std::max() function in chapter "Header <algorithm> synopsis" (chapter 27.4 in C++23 draft N4928).
This question is not a duplicate of Why does omission of "#include " only sometimes cause compilation failures?. I know why it compiles. It compiles because std::max() is defined directly or indirectly in <utility>. None of the answers there gives a reference to the specification.
Same for Why can std::max and std::min still be used even if I didn't #include ? and Can std::string be used without #include ? and Why Is it possible to use std::thread without #include thread in c++? . Those not language-lawyer questions and none of them gives specification references.

The code as written does not follow the rules given by the Standard, because it says that std::max is declared by <algorithm>. Since this header isn't included, it is moot to ask if the Standard allows it ("undefined behavior").

The standard strictly defines  and  explicit API. Visual Studio, which then decided that  requires less lines of code to be included This even isn't guaranteed in future VS updates.

@j6t: yes, I'm definitely not happy with the code. I want <algorithm> to be included. So I consider this a bug of the MSVC utility library.

I am not a language lawyer, but I am pretty sure this is allowed for an implementation to include other headers in standard headers.

Nothing prevents standard header files from including other standard header files.
Just include the one defined by specification. The fact that utility contains std::max() might be an implementation detail, not any sort of extension. This happens for most, if not all mainstream compilers and I doubt it it's even meant to be an extension.

In short:  yes. The standard does NOT disallow standard headers #includeing each other beyond what the standard requires (in your case, <utility> is not required to declare std::max()).  Vendors also often provide some vendor-specific extensions in standard headers. These add to portability challenges - your code might (for example) compile with one compiler, but fail with another. To ensure portability, you must be quite strategic (#include all standard headers that the standard specifies as needed for all functions/types you use, avoid using vendor-specific extensions).

So, long story short, I will not use the "optimize include graph" function any more. I thought it's a built-in of IWYU which I don't have up and running yet.

@ThomasWeller I don't know IWYU too much, but couldn't it be set not to optimize standard headers?

If you care about portability, you can't treat the "optimize include graph" feature as a "set and forget".   You will need to review what it does, and manually accept/reject any changes it makes.      At best, the feature can only be "set and forget" if you stick to using only MSVC (and, even then, may still break your builds with future updates of MSVC).   Running the code through multiple toolchains (and multiple versions) can increase the odds of your code being portable, but there is a non-zero chance of something slipping through the checks.

@ThomasWeller "None of the answers there gives a reference to the specification...." Check again. The first dupe(around 9 years old) has the answer you're looking for. It says: "A C++ header may include other C++ headers." with the c++ standard reference.

The actual bug that needs a report is that "windows.h" and other none-std headers define min and max as macros and cause conflicts.

@user12002570: I have not mentioned the first one as not being a dupe. Still, I don't think it's appropriate to spam a lot of dupes, which actually aren't.

@user12002570 I've reopened this. Only the first dupe was relevant (the rest don't cite the standard), and it quotes the same question as I do in my deleted answer. The problem with this quote is that it only allows the whole headers to be included, not parts of it as happens here.

@HolyBlackCat Then the as-if rule can be added as a dupe. Implementations are allowed to do anything as long as the observed behavior matches the one mandated by the standard.

That would be [intro.abstract] (4.1.2 in N4928), https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#5

@user12002570 Huh. How is it related to allowing headers add extra declarations?

@HolyBlackCat Headers can add as many declarations as they want as long as it doesn't change the observed behavior and that matches the one with the standard specified behavior.

I generally agree,  may declare std::max() because that behaves as if it #included . I'm just a little bit worried about the one definition rule, but to be honest, I have a hard time reading that cryptic max() template and figuring out why they do it and why it's needed.

Only including whole headers is also not possible because of circular dependensies. For example <ranges> uses iterator_traits and <iterator> must contain ranges::begin.

@user12002570 I don't think the as-if rule allows that. The standard says that if you call a non-existent function then your program is ill-formed. The compiler isn't allowed to make it well-formed by adding arbitrary function declarations. (At least not in general, there could be something specifically for std.)

@HolyBlackCat Making the program from ill-formed to well-formed(or vice-versa) is a change in behavior. So that is not what I am talking about. I am talking about when there is no change in behavior from the one mandated.

@user12002570 I'm sorry, I'm not following. How can it not be a change in behavior if you're calling a function that wasn't declared? That should make the program ill-formed. Or, if the implementation chose to transitively include an extra header, then it has to add all the declarations in it (or at least that's what my quote seems to say, I know that no implementation does it).

@HolyBlackCat But msvc does have the declations for max in the shown post in the header OP's including.

Why it's required to include vector (and other headers too) in global namespace only?

@Red.Wave You can avoid that by defining NOMINMAX.

@Craig thanks. I used to play preprocessor hackathon(basically #undef). MSVC defaults are often wrong. std behavior is opt-in, instead of opt-out for none-std.

using.headers#3 says:

A translation unit [...] shall include the header [...] lexically before the first reference in that translation unit to any of the entities declared in that header. No diagnostic is required.

The code references std::max, but includes only <utility>. Yet, utility.syn does not list max anywhere. Therefore, the program has undefined behavior is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.
That the program still compiles, does not make it correct. Nevertheless, the compiler is conforming because it is not required to diagnose that <algorithm>, where std::max is actually declared, was not included.

So this is ill-formed NDR, not just UB.

@HolyBlackCat Ah, right! The use "shall" indicates that. Fixed.

I agree. But that answers a different question, doesn't it?

@ThomasWeller Maybe. The corollary of this answer is "when a program is wrong, the compiler can do whatever it wants", but I am a bit reluctant to write this into the answer.

"Ill-formed, no diagnostic required" means "This is not a legal C++ program, the compiler is not required to tell you that it is not a legal C++ program and the compiler is permitted to produce a program that does anything imaginable." A program that uses std::min without including <algorithm> is therefore IFNDR and although the compiler is permitted to reject the program, it is also permitted to accept the program, and it is permitted even to accept the program and behave as if <algorithm> had been included all along.

@HolyBlackCat  this is ill-formed NDR, not just UB What is the difference?

@LanguageLawyer Good question. :) I believe IF NDR implies UB? Are you saying that the difference is purely semantic?

UB can be conditional based on program state, whereas I think IF NDR is unconditional.  (There's obviously a convergence where it's trivially possible to write a program that will exhibit UB in every possible execution, but I think that's mostly more in the realm of toy problems.)

UB means "If this line of code ever executes, you're in big trouble!" IFNDR means "Your program is in big trouble even before it executes a single line of code!"

@HolyBlackCat https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/defns.undefined https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/intro.compliance.general#2.2 they both mean the same thing, that the spec imposes no requirements

@RaymondChen UB means "If this line of code ever executes, you're in big trouble!" UB can "occur" at any stage, including preprocessing

@j6t: you spot that OP code is ill-formed, but you didn't answer the question ;-) Using SFINAE/concept to check if std::max(const MyObject&, const MyObject&) is present and another function from <algorithm> might be done without being ill-formed.

As this code if I am correct.
